# Accessing SP List using Rest-APi

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, rest, client-object-model, authentication

```
 var url = serverRelativeUrl + "MyServer/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/items";

        var httpRequest = $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url,
            crossDomain: true,
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          //some stuff here
      }
```

When I login as site collection administrator, I can access Test list successfully, but when i login as ordinary site user, i could not access list data.

I am not sure but It looks like some authentication and/or List permission issue.
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What permission does the normal user have on the site and the list?

Comment: Read access on site & list.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Can you please post it?